# Cassandra connection pooling using hector

Tags: cassandra, hector

How can i create a connection pool for cassandra using hector? can somebody give a simple example for this. i have searched the net but didn't get any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hector handles the [connection pooling](https://github.com/hector-client/hector/wiki/User-Guide#pools-of-pools-per-server) for you. From their [docs](https://github.com/hector-client/hector/wiki/User-Guide#basic-configuration-and-setup):

> The basic design of connection pooling logic in Hector is to create a master pool of individual pools of connections based on the number of Cassandra nodes explicitly identified to Hector. For example, if we had three Cassandra nodes configured, HConnectionManager would contain three individual pools of connections – one for each node.
>
> ...
>
> The underlying HConnectionManager as well as the host-specific pool for localhost:9160 will both be created automatically if they do not already exist.

You can also read through all the possible [configuration options](https://github.com/hector-client/hector/wiki/User-Guide#finer-grained-configuration) of the connection and pooling settings.